# Repopulating Django ChoiceField Without Restarting Server

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I have a simple form where users can select a department from a choicefield.

This is my form :

```
class NewDealForm1(forms.Form):
        department = forms.ChoiceField(choices = map(lambda x:('%s'% x.id, '%s' % x.title),Department.objects.all()))
```

Whenever I add a new department from admin, my choicefield doesn't display new department unless I restart my server.

How can i display all departments without restarting the server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `forms.ChoiceField` you should try a `forms.ModelChoiceField` which takes a queryset directly.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Example

```
class NewDealForm1(forms.Form):
    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Department.objects.all()))
```

Answer (score 4):

Wolph's answer is correct.

But to answer your question directly ("Repopulating Django ChoiceField Without Restarting Server"), you'd need to set the choices in your form constructor. Here's an example for a dynamic credit card year choice.

```
class NewDealForm1(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[]))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewDealForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        year = datetime.date.today().year
        self.fields['year'].choices = [(x, x) for x in range(year, year+10)]
```